# How would reals be implemented in Cubical Agda?

Tags: agda, cubical-type-theory

Right now I am studying how reals are done in Coq, but I remember a while back watching Bauer's lectures and hearing him state that HoTT has a different and better way of defining reals that either the Cauchy sequences or Dedekind cuts. I am not sure if the same applies to Cubical Agda, but for that reason I am asking. I know that the HoTT book has a section on this, but it is too much for me at the moment.

I'd be interested seeing code examples in Cubical Agda so I can contrast them with the Coq ones.

Comment: As of Agda 2.6.0.1 with `--cubical`, the higher inductive real numbers covered in section 11.3.1 of the HoTT book are not supported, because indexed higher inductive types are not supported in general. It is under development AFAIK.

Comment: I guess this question should be revisited in the future then. What are indexed HITs?

Comment: In Agda, an indexed inductive type has one or more input type on the right of the `:` in a type constructor, e.g. `data D : Bool -> Set` where `Bool` is the indexing type.

Comment: So an indexed HIT then would be such an data type that has path constructors? Still, I am trying a few trivial examples of what could be indexed HITs and Cubical Agda does seem to support them.

Comment: Agda 2.6.0.1 doesn't outright reject indexed HITs, but it does not add any computation rules for composition on the constructors of the HIT. This makes them effectively unusable.

Comment: What do you mean by composition on the constructors of the HIT?

Comment: Basically `transport (\ i -> H ?) u` will get stuck if `H` is a indexed inductive type (higher or not), otherwise they still behave as in plain Agda or Coq.

Comment: You could, instead of using indexed types, put an extra field in your constructor that witnesses the equality between "index" (that would be just a parameter) and the fiber base point.

Comment: Is there a tracking issue for this?

Comment: @Dylan yes, https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/3733